# SQL Show only rows from both tables when joined PK count is greater than a criteria

Tags: sql

Table Adult:

```
id, Adname   
1 , Harry 
2 , Sally 
3 , Beth 
4 , David
```

Table Children:

```
id, Chname  , adult_id , DOB(YYYY-MM-DD) 
1 , Rebecca , 1        , 5/23/1987 
2 , Stanley , 3        , 9/7/2003
3 , Emma    , 3        , 3/17/2000 
4 , Maria   , 4        , 11/8/1995
5 , Michael , 4        , 8/15/1998
6 , Jessica , 4        , 4/28/1991
```

Query: Show the adults and their children for only the adults with 2 or more children.
So far I have:

```
SELECT Adult.Adname, COUNT(Children.Adult_id) AS NumberOfChildren FROM (Adult
INNER JOIN Children
ON Adult.ID=Children.Adult_id)
GROUP BY Adname
HAVING COUNT (Children.Adult_id) > 2
UNION SELECT Adult.Adname, Children.Chname
FROM Adult LEFT JOIN Children ON Adult.[ID] = Children.[Adult_id]
WHERE Children.Adult_id <> NULL;
```

but the result still shows the adults and children for less than 2 ??

Comment: `WHERE Children.Adult_id <> NULL`? This will never be true unless some options are set. Which database do you use?

Comment: Adult ID will NOT EQUAL Null, this will ALWAYS be true in Table Children, and I don't need this line, I need something different, yes. Thanx

Comment: Test for null is usually performed using `is null` or `is not null`. That's why I have asked for RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you don't specify an expected output example, I understand that you want to show the adult's name and their child's names:

```
SELECT Adult.Adname, Children.Chname
FROM Adult INNER JOIN Children
ON Children.Adult_Id = Adult.ID
WHERE Adult.ID IN
(SELECT Adult_id 
FROM Children
GROUP BY Adult_id
HAVING COUNT (Children.Adult_id) > 2)
```

Comment: This produces the desired results, I will review use of "IN", thanx a bunch

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT a.*, c.*
FROM Adults a
JOIN (
    SELECT AdultId
    FROM Children
    GROUP BY AdultId
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
) n
ON n.AdultId = a.Id
JOIN Children c
ON c.AdultId = n.AdultId
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1078b/1)

Answer (score 0):

What Sachin said. Get rid of the union part. Probably what was intended was to move the where clause from the unioned statement into the original statement like this:

```
SELECT Adult.Adname, COUNT(Children.Adult_id) AS NumberOfChildren FROM (Adult
INNER JOIN Children
ON Adult.ID=Children.Adult_id)
WHERE Children.Adult_id <> NULL
GROUP BY Adname
HAVING COUNT (Children.Adult_id) > 2
```

Comment: My logic was off here, I see it now... c.Adult_id <> null will always be true (unless data entry error), so the result of this will show the NumberofChildren just fine, but not their names.

Comment: I see, so you want to show the children's names as well as the count of children?

Comment: If you want to show count of children for each adult, as well as their names, I guess I can add that? but the code given that operates is okay.